# Verbose javascript conditional seeks simplification

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, modulo

I have the following rather verbose conditional, I'm trying to wrap my head around a simpler version but I'm not getting anywhere.

```
if( agent % $.settings.gridSize === 0 && value % $.settings.gridSize == 1 ){
    // Dud
}else if(agent % $.settings.gridSize == 1 && value % $.settings.gridSize === 0){
    // Dud
}else{
    freeCells.push(value);
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve the same condition with a single `if` statement, rather than using the throw-away `if else`?

Something like:

```
if(!(a && b) && !(x && y)){
   // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: What is `//Dud`? Is it the same thing twice?

Comment: You could simplify to `if ((!a || !b) && (!x || !y)` (or, alternatively, to `if (!(a && b || x && y))`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and you've (almost) answered your question yourself.

You can do the following:

```
var gS = $.settings.gridSize;

if(!(agent % gS === 0 && value % gS == 1) && !(agent % gS == 1 && value % gS === 0)) {
    freeCells.push(value);
}
```

Comment: Oh, ha! Good stuff. You left the modulo in the variable declaration by the way, happy to accept as correct answer if you remove the 'agent %'.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the possible values of $.settings.gridSize etc., it's possible that what you are looking for is:

```
if (agent % $.settings.gridSize !== value % $.settings.gridSize) {
    // Dud
} else {
```

which also makes the semantics clearer: the modulo involving `agent` should be "different" (in the `0/1` sense) from the module involving `value`.

Comment: I also think the only reasonable value of `$.settings.gridSize` is 2. Wouldn't the semantics become even clearer when you replace the variable by this magic number?

Comment: @Robert unusual assumption, that variable can be anything (up to 512). torazaburo  - interesting, you may well be right, I'll have to go back and check, wouldn't be the first time I'd over thought something!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (
    agent % $.settings.gridSize > 1
    ||
    (agent + value) % $.settings.gridSize !== 1
) {
    freeCells.push(value);
}
```

I think it's pretty self-explaining.

**Edit**

Seems like it isn't that self-explaining actually.

I made a few assumptions for the transformation.

1. `// Dud` means to do nothing.
2. `$.settings.gridSize` is a positive integer, henceforth referred to as `gridSize`.
3. `agent` and `value` are non-negative integers.

For a `value` **not** to be pushed `agent % gridSize` has to be either `0` or `1`. Since there are no negative numbers or fractional parts involved this means the same as `agent % gridSize <= 1`. So if the remainder is greater than `1` then `value` gets pushed.

Otherwise `agent % gridSize` is either `0` or `1`. And for the `value` not to be pushed `value % gridSize` has to take on the respective other value. In total this would mean that `(agent + value) % gridSize === 1`. So if it's not `1` then `value` gets pushed.

Comment: Not really. Could you please explain what semantics you use for the transformation and which edge cases you ignored? I'd be particularly interested in where you got that `> 1` from.

Comment: @Bergi Of course. Somehow I expected someone to become suspicious. I tried my best to explain the transformation but it got a bit more complicated than expected. Sadly I have little experience.